# Oracle issue porting working SQL to procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have some SQL, which works fine. Inside the SQL are hard coded dates, which I want to remove and pass them in from a procedure.

When I try to create the procedure, which does the inserts I am getting the following error and I don't understand why its happening. It's the same code in the SELECT statement with an INSERT statement right above the SELECT.

```
Errors: PROCEDURE CREATE_TIMEOFF_REQUESTS
Line/Col: 7/1 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Line/Col: 10/19 PL/SQL: ORA-01744: inappropriate INTO
```

Below is my test case. I'm testing in Live SQL so we can both have the same Oracle version. Any help fixing my code would be greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE obj_date IS OBJECT (
  date_val DATE
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE nt_date IS TABLE OF obj_date;

create or replace function generate_dates_pipelined(
  p_from  in date,
  p_to    in date
)
  return nt_date 
  pipelined
is
begin
  for c1 in (
    with calendar (start_date, end_date ) as (
      select trunc(p_from), trunc(p_to) from dual
      union all
      select start_date + 1, end_date
      from   calendar
      where  start_date + 1 <= end_date
    )
    select start_date as day
    from   calendar
  ) loop
    pipe row  (obj_date(c1.day));
  end loop;
 
  return;
end       generate_dates_pipelined;

create table holidays(
  holiday_date DATE not null,
  holiday_name VARCHAR2(20),
  constraint holidays_pk primary key (holiday_date),
  constraint is_midnight check ( holiday_date = trunc ( holiday_date ) )
);

INSERT into holidays (HOLIDAY_DATE,HOLIDAY_NAME)
WITH dts as (
  select to_date('01-AUG-2021 00:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'August  1st 2021' from dual union all
  select to_date('05-AUG-2021 00:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'August  5th 2021' from dual
)
SELECT * from dts;

Create table employees(
  employee_id NUMBER(6), 
  first_name VARCHAR2(20),
  last_name VARCHAR2(20),
  card_num VARCHAR2(10),
  work_days VARCHAR2(7)
);

ALTER TABLE employees
ADD (
  CONSTRAINT employees_pk PRIMARY KEY (employee_id)
      );

INSERT INTO employees (
  EMPLOYEE_ID,
  first_name, 
  last_name,
  card_num,
  work_days
)
WITH names AS ( 
  SELECT 1, 'Jane',     'Doe',      'F123456', 'NYYYYYN'   FROM dual UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2, 'Madison', 'Smith', 'R33432','NYYYYYN' FROM dual UNION ALL 
  SELECT 3, 'Justin',   'Case',     'C765341','NYYYYYN' FROM dual UNION ALL 
  SELECT 4, 'Mike',     'Jones',      'D564311','NYYYYYN' FROM dual 
)
SELECT * FROM names;  
  
create table timeoff(
    seq_num integer  GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
  employee_id NUMBER(6),
  timeoff_date DATE,
  timeoff_type VARCHAR2(1) DEFAULT 'V',
  constraint timeoff_chk check (timeoff_date=trunc(timeoff_date, 'dd')),
  constraint timeoff_pk primary key (employee_id, timeoff_date)
);
```

SQL works:

```
INSERT INTO timeoff (employee_id, timeoff_date)
SELECT e.employee_id,
       c.date_val
FROM   employees e
       INNER JOIN table(generate_dates_pipelined(date '2021-08-01', DATE '2021-08-10')) c
       PARTITION BY ( e.employee_id )
       ON (SUBSTR(e.work_days, TRUNC(c.date_val) - TRUNC(c.date_val, 'IW') + 1, 1) = 'Y')
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM   holidays h
         WHERE  c.date_val = h.holiday_date
       )
ORDER BY
      e.employee_id,
      c.date_val
;

SELECT * from timeoff;

SEQ_NUM    EMPLOYEE_ID    TIMEOFF_DATE    TIMEOFF_TYPE
1    1    03-AUG-21    V
2    1    04-AUG-21    V
3    1    06-AUG-21    V
4    1    07-AUG-21    V
5    1    10-AUG-21    V
6    2    03-AUG-21    V
7    2    04-AUG-21    V
8    2    06-AUG-21    V
...
...

TRUNCATE table timeoff;
```

Procedure with SELECT creates and RUN

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_timeoff_requests (start_date DATE, end_date DATE)
IS
    type t_date is table of date;
    l_res t_date;

BEGIN

      SELECT 
     c.date_val
     BULK COLLECT INTO l_res
     FROM   employees e
      INNER JOIN  TABLE (generate_dates_pipelined (start_date, end_date))c
    PARTITION BY ( e.employee_id )
            ON (SUBSTR(e.work_days, TRUNC(c.date_val) - TRUNC(c.date_val, 'IW') + 1, 1) = 'Y')
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT 1
            FROM   holidays h
           WHERE    c.date_val = h.holiday_date
           )
    ORDER BY
       e.employee_id,
        c.date_val;


   -- debug
     for i in 1..l_res.count  loop
        dbms_output.put_line(l_res(i));
       end loop;
END;


EXEC create_timeoff_requests (DATE '2021-08-01', DATE '2021-08-10');

    03-AUG-21
    04-AUG-21
    06-AUG-21
    07-AUG-21
    10-AUG-21
    03-AUG-21
    04-AUG-21
    06-AUG-21
    07-AUG-21
    10-AUG-21
    ...
    ...
```

Fails to create with added INSERT statement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_timeoff_requests (start_date DATE, end_date DATE)
IS
    type t_date is table of date;
    l_res t_date;

BEGIN
  INSERT INTO timeoff (employee_id, timeoff_date)  
       SELECT 
     c.date_val
     BULK COLLECT INTO l_res
     FROM   employees e
      INNER JOIN  TABLE (generate_dates_pipelined (start_date, end_date))c
    PARTITION BY ( e.employee_id )
            ON (SUBSTR(e.work_days, TRUNC(c.date_val) - TRUNC(c.date_val, 'IW') + 1, 1) = 'Y')
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT 1
            FROM   holidays h
            WHERE  c.date_val = h.holiday_date
           )
    ORDER BY
        e.employee_id,
 c.date_val;


   -- debug
     for i in 1..l_res.count  loop
      dbms_output.put_line(l_res(i));
       end loop;
END;
```

Comment: You can insert the results of a query directly into a table; or you can query them into a collection; but you can't do both in the same single statement. Once you have the collection you can do a bulk insert into the table; but do you actually *want* or need the collection?

Comment: @Alex Poole I need the collection because I am calling a pipelined function that returns 1 or more dates and I didn't know how to capture the results. That is an example I found with Google. Any coding changes you could provide would be greatly appreciated as I am a DBA who was thrown a development project because something was needed yesterday.

Comment: Pipelined function is a data source, so it can appear in every place where table may be used. You can select from it directly, just copy your `insert` statement and paste it directly into PL/SQL code as is.

Comment: Your "SQL works" version is calling the pipelined function; that can be moved directly into PL/SQL, and you can just replace the fixed dates with the procedure arguments. I'm not sure why you added a collection. Why do you need to "capture the results" - does that just mean insert them, or something else on top of that?

Comment: @astentx my INSERT statement is within PLSQL procedure. I'm unsure what you are saying.

Comment: As Alex said above you do not need an intermediary storage, just put your `insert` as is, without `BULK COLLECT INTO l_res`.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need an object to wrap a `DATE` and can just use:

```sql
CREATE TYPE nt_date IS TABLE OF DATE;
```

You can rewrite your calendar function to:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION generate_dates_pipelined(
  p_from IN DATE,
  p_to   IN DATE
)
  RETURN nt_date PIPELINED DETERMINISTIC
IS
  v_start DATE := TRUNC(LEAST(p_from, p_to));
  v_end   DATE := TRUNC(GREATEST(p_from, p_to));
BEGIN
  LOOP
    PIPE ROW (v_start);
    EXIT WHEN v_start >= v_end;
    v_start := v_start + INTERVAL '1' DAY;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END generate_dates_pipelined;
```

Your function to insert time off almost certainly wants to take an employee as an argument (otherwise you are inserting leave for **ALL** employees) and you probably want to use `MERGE` so that employees do not insert multiple requests for the same day if they submit overlapping requests.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE create_timeoff_requests (
  p_employee_id IN TIMEOFF.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE,
  p_start_date  IN TIMEOFF.TIMEOFF_DATE%TYPE,
  p_end_date    IN TIMEOFF.TIMEOFF_DATE%TYPE
)
IS
BEGIN
  MERGE INTO timeoff dst
  USING (
    SELECT e.employee_id,
           c.COLUMN_VALUE AS timeoff_date
    FROM   employees e
           INNER JOIN TABLE(
             generate_dates_pipelined(p_start_date, p_end_date)
           ) c
           ON (SUBSTR(e.work_days, TRUNC(c.COLUMN_VALUE) - TRUNC(c.COLUMN_VALUE, 'IW') + 1, 1) = 'Y')
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
             SELECT 1
             FROM   holidays h
             WHERE  c.COLUMN_VALUE = h.holiday_date
           )
    AND    e.employee_id = p_employee_id
  ) src
  ON (    src.employee_id  = dst.employee_id
      AND src.timeoff_date = dst.timeoff_date )
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (employee_id, timeoff_date)
    VALUES (src.employee_id, src.timeoff_date);
END;
/
```

Comment: @MTO when I try to create your version of the pipelined function I get the following error. Errors: FUNCTION GENERATE_DATES_PIPELINED
Line/Col: 11/5 PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Line/Col: 11/15 PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

Comment: @Beefstu Have you replaced the `TYPE`? If you haven't then it is still expecting a table of objects rather than a table of dates. My code works if you use the correct types.

Comment: @MTO yes I plan on passing an employee_id but that will come later as I was struggling with this issue. Thanks for your help and patience its appreciated. Sorry for all the problems and questions

Comment: @MTO I didn't change the types as they are being used all over the place.  I will create a new one with a different name with the syntax you provided

Comment: It may be worth to remove a pipelined function at all and use a calendar table with all the required attributes like holiday flag. For 30 years it will occupy just 10-15 db blocks which will be cached.

Comment: @MTO does your new version if the calendar function return the same as the one as I was using. As I mentioned this is being called all over in many systems and I don't want to break anything.

Comment: @Beefstu You should test it to make sure it does. However, it should return the same values when `p_start_date <= p_end_date`; if you pass values where `p_start_date > p_end_date` then the behaviour is different (but it is easy to revert to the previous behaviour by just removing the `GREATEST`/`LEAST` function calls in the variable declaration).

Comment: @MTO your suggestion appears to work great!! I was using the unique key error table to avoid violations, it was kluny. The MERGE code is so much better. Thanks for your help and expertise. I can only hope that the success of your solution doesn't inundate me with more coding projects :-)

Comment: @MTO I hope you don't mind one more question that is most likely a cinch for you.

In my timeoff table I use the following 

    timeoff_type VARCHAR2(1) DEFAULT 'V',

How can I modify the code to check and see if the caller supplied a value? If so, use it, if not then the default definition in the table will be used. Would it be a  IS NULL test?

ie I want to pass 'L' for LOA.

EXEC create_timeoff_requests (1, DATE '2021-08-01', DATE '2021-08-10', 'L');

Comment: @Beefstu Have the function take a 4th argument with a default value `p_timeoff_type IN TIMEOFF.TIMEOFF_TYPE%TYPE DEFAULT 'L'` and then pass that into the `INSERT` clause of the `MERGE` statement `INSERT (employee_id, timeoff_date, timeoff_type) VALUES (src.employee_id, src.timeoff_date, p_timeoff_type);`

Comment: @MTO kudos, you make it look so easy and saved me the rest of the time googling. You da man!! If a I'm in a bind again, which I suspect will be shortly, I hope you are out there. THANKS for your help, patience and expertise

Answer (score 1):

You can insert the results of a query directly into a table; or you can query them into a collection; but you can't do both in the same single statement.

> I need the collection because I am calling a pipelined function that returns 1 or more dates and I didn't know how to capture the results.

The pipelined function doesn't need a collection; you're already calling that from your "SQL works" standalone version. You can move that directly into your procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_timeoff_requests (start_date DATE, end_date DATE)
IS
    type t_date is table of date;
    l_res t_date;

BEGIN
  INSERT INTO timeoff (employee_id, timeoff_date)
  SELECT e.employee_id,
         c.date_val
  FROM   employees e
         INNER JOIN table(generate_dates_pipelined(start_date, end_date)) c
         PARTITION BY ( e.employee_id )
         ON (SUBSTR(e.work_days, TRUNC(c.date_val) - TRUNC(c.date_val, 'IW') + 1, 1) = 'Y')
  WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT 1
           FROM   holidays h
           WHERE  c.date_val = h.holiday_date
         );
END create_timeoff_requests;
/
```

The only difference is changing:

```
INNER JOIN table(generate_dates_pipelined(date '2021-08-01', DATE '2021-08-10')) c
```

to

```
INNER JOIN table(generate_dates_pipelined(start_date, end_date)) c
```

so it uses the procedure arguments (though you might consider renaming those as `p_start_date` and `p_end_date` to match the prefix pattern used by your `generate_dates_pipelined` function, and reduce the likelihood of an argument/column name clash down the line). And the `order by` is redundant when inserting.

Comment: thanks for the feedback and your expertise